# How to programatically link payment with an order in Drupal commerce?

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways

Version: Drupal Commerce 2.x.

I am creating orders programatically by following the instruction from the [documentation](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders). I looked for various resources but couldn't find any way to link payment with the orders created programatically. Is there a way to create payment instance and link it to order.

Comment: Payments have a required order_id field, that's the only thing needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help